Friday Night in Kotzk
There is a story about the Kotzker Rebbe that says he disregarded or left Yiddishkeit by flagrantly desecrating the Shabbos by blowing out Shabbos candles, taking off his Yarmulke and smoking a pipe, or throwing the Kiddush cup on the ground in order to show disrespect to the sanctification of Shabbos.
I also heard that there was a fiery/heated debate between him and the Ishbitzer Rebbe (Mordechai Yosef Leiner) and he left Kotzk.
Please give me clarification, as I don't want to believe that this is true, because I look up to him as a tzaddik.
Edit: Here is one of the pages that refers to what I'm talking about: https://www.kotzkblog.com/2023/02/416-what-really-happened-on-last-friday.html
There is another page where I originally read it from: https://www.academia.edu/36793911/The_RADZYNER_REBBE_DYNASTY_1840_2005_by_MEIR_Halevi_GOVER

To make this question more answerable, could you please [edit] to add more information about where you heard these stories and what information in particular you're looking for?

Blasphemous....

@IsaacMoses I have edited the page. Hopefully this offers enough information!

Gershon, thanks for adding the links! There's a great deal of information in the resources you linked to. Could you please edit your question to express what you're missing and looking for?

Those who know what happened don’t say, and those who say don’t know…

There are a couple books by Elie Weisel that relate the Chassidic stories he heard growing up. He mentions a few of the versions floating around in his day, but it seems no one really knew back then either. If the story did happen, it would seem to indicate a mental break of psychosis or dementia, which would not diminish his earlier tzidkus.
